# open modal with data attributes is not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have this code below to show in a table info about registrations in a specific congress:

```
@foreach($conference->registrations as $registration)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$registration->customer->name}} {{$registration->customer->surname}}</td>
        <td>{{ $registration->participants->count() }}</td>
        ...
        <td>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" id="showDetails"  data-regid="{{$registration->id}}">Details</a>
        </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

But then with the "Details" link is to open a modal that it is in this page so is possible to show the details of that specific registration. But since each registration needs to have its own modal to show its specific details I put the modal inside the foreach and add registration id like  "id="registrationDetails-{{ $registration->id }}".

But its not working properly when the "Details" link is clicked in any row the modal dont appears.

Do you know where is the issue?

The modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade"  id="registrationDetails-{{ $registration->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

            <!-- User that did the registration -->
            <dl>
              <dt>Name</dt>
              <dd>{{ $registration->customer->name }}</dd>
              <dt>Email</dt>
              <dd>{{ $registration->customer->email }}</dd>
            </dl>

            @foreach ($registration->participants as $participant)

            <!-- Participant N -->
            <dl>
              <dt>Name</dt>
              <dd>{{ $participant->name }}</dd>
              <dt>Surname</dt>
              <dd>{{ $participant->surname }}</dd>
              <dt>Ticket Type</dt>
              <dd>{{ $participant->ticket_type->name }}</dd>
            </dl>

            @endforeach
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="close_login_modal" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
   @section('scripts')

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url('js/jquery-ui.js')}}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            $(".showDetails").on("click", function () {
                alert("test");
                let regID = $(this).data('regid');
                alert(regID);

                $('#registrationDetails-'+regID).modal('show');
            });

        });

        </script>
@endsection
```

Comment: You don't seem to have a <script> tag before your `$(function()`

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question to correct that, but same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM ids should be unique, but you have multiple `#showDetail` ids.

Change it to a class:

```
@foreach($conference->registrations as $registration)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$registration->customer->name}} {{$registration->customer->surname}}</td>
        <td>{{ $registration->participants->count() }}</td>
        ...
        <td>
        <a class="btn btn-primary showDetails" data-regid="{{$registration->id}}">Details</a>
        </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

And

```
$(".showDetails").on("click", function () {
    let regID = $(this).data('regid');
    alert(regID);

    $('#registrationDetails-'+regID).modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but same issue.

Comment: Does the alert (and event) trigger?

Comment: No, this alert dont appear " $(".showDetails").on("click", function () {
                alert("test");....".

Comment: In my original answer I added a separate `class="showDetails`, when you already have the `class` defined. Try with my update: `<a class="btn btn-primary showDetails" data-regid="{{$registration->id}}">Details</a>`

Comment: Thanks, now both alerts alert("test") and alert(regID) shows, the alert(regID) shows the correct registration id but the modal donta appears.

Comment: I have 4 registrations for now and for one registration the modal appears ,for the others dont. It is working only for the last registration.

Comment: That's weird. Can you double check in the page source (Ctrl + U) that the modals have correct IDs and check that the alerts show the correct ID (when clicked)

Comment: Maybe the issue is that, checking the source code with  (Ctrl + U),  there is only one modal that has "id="registrationDetails-2".

Comment: Should it be only one modal on the page? In the other registrations where the modal dont appears the alert shows the correct id of that clicked registration "Details" link the issue is that the modal dont appears.

Comment: Yeah that's the issue. Put the modals within the `foreach($conference->registrations)`. Now it only prints the modal for the last registration (the one that is assigned at the end of your upper `foreach`)

Comment: No, for that to work, you need to have a separate modal for each registration.

Comment: Thanks, like that it works, but is ok to have the modal in the foreach? In terms of performance I dont know if there is some issue.

Comment: It's not *wrong* and it's by far the easiest way to implement it. Other way would be to assign all the attributes to the button (with `data-...`, like you did for the `ID` and fill them dynamically on the modal when the modal is clicked.